# Count how many times a number appeared within a range of that list

Tags: c#, linq

I need to count how many times a real number `int n;` appears in my list, but the tricky part, is within a specific range of that list between `list.Count-x` and `list.Count-y`

Comment: Would you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Skip` and `Take` to get the range you need:

```
var count = list
    .Skip(startIndex)
    .Take(length)
    .Count(i => i == n);
```

Comment: im not a programmer so i dont really know what to search for since i dont know how stuff is called

Answer (score 1):

Linq makes it easy.

```
int start = 3;
int range = 5;
int search = -8;
var result = list.Skip(start).Take(range).Count(i => i == search);
```

This will start from `start` and will count up to `start + range`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Where` overload:

```
var result = list.Where((elem, index) => elem == n 
                                         && index >= list.Count -x  
                                         && index <= list.Count - y)
                 .Count();
```

Another option:

```
var result = list.GetRange(startIndex, cnt).Count(elem => elem == n);
```